# What are the dangers of using IE 7 compatibility mode in IE 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners, ie8-compatibility-mode

I just wanted to get people's take on using the IE7 compatibility meta tag in IE8 to render pages via IE7 rather than IE8?

This topic doesn't seem to have been mentioned for a while, but with the relatively recent news that Microsoft will be implementing automatic updates for IE, this means that IE7 will be phased out soon.

Is it a really really bad move to use the IE7 compatibility tag in a site NOW? The reason being? rounded corners. I have a site which heavily depends on rounded corners, and so rather than using loads of Png's specific for IE, i would love to implement the DD_roundies technique, which seems to only work effectively in IE7, not IE8. (using parallels anyway, which i don't 100% trust).

What are your thoughts people?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a really really bad move to use the IE7 compatibility tag in a site NOW?

Yes, it means your code is broken. Rather than using compatibility hacks, **you should fix your code**. It's a bug that it ever worked correctly in the first place.

Also, it's worth noting that the compatibility mode switch is there for the *user*, not for the programmer. The programmer has control over her code, and she can test and *fix* it to make sure that it works properly. The user can't do this, so he has to resort to hacks like compatibility mode.

> ...with the relatively recent news that Microsoft will be implementing automatic updates for IE, this means that IE7 will be phased out soon.

IE 7 has *already* been phased out. Automatic updates may help prod some users into making the leap, but there's no guarantee that it will make a difference for everyone. If you must target the broadest possible base, you'll still need to support IE 7 for a while longer.

And even if IE 7 *does* go away, IE 8 isn't going to go away for quite a while longer, considering that IE 9 is not supported on Windows XP. You'll need to make your code work in IE 8 *then*, so why not do it *now*?

Answer (score 0):

Using IE7 mode means your code is broken.  It will be harder to make it work in standard browsers, and of course as time goes on it will just get worse.

DD_Roundies is unsupported by its author and is considered dead.  Leave it that way.

Use a more modern library for rounded corners, like [CSS 3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: Hey guys,

Thanks for your replies. You're totally right, i really didn't like the idea of using the Emulator, so since then i have had another look at CSS3pie, and this time, i have got it to work! :D. Very happy man right now.

The reason why it wasn't working, was to do with the reference path to the file. This has to be from the HTML NOT the CSS. BOOM, it's now working. Problem solved!

Bye bye IE7! Hoorah!